# SSRS. How to merge cells using expressions?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have 3 columns and here are 2 possible ways:

```
1. In all of them are values 
2. Only col1 keeps value (col2 and col3 NULL)
```

For now It looks like:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
| val1 |      |      |
| val2 | val3 | val4 |
| val5 | val6 | val7 |
| val8 |      |      |
```

It should be like this:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
|        val1        | -- merged cells, because col2 and col3 empty
| val2 | val3 | val4 |
| val5 | val6 | val7 |
|        val8        | -- merged cells, because col2 and col3 empty
```

I don't have idea If I need to create groups (I've tried row/column grouping, but really unsuccessfully, far away from what I need).

As I think I need to write expression something like:

```
IFF(col2 & col3 = NULL) MERGE(col1, col2, col3)
```

Just I can't get success with expression's structure.

Comment: So you want to merge all cells when col2 and col3 both are null. Otherwise you want to display them as it is in the report. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if col2 and col 3 both are null, should merge col1, col2, col3 and keep only value from col1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think in SSRS it is possible to merge cells dynamically using expressions. Only way I can think of is having a fourth text box(Probably below the 3 on top) which contains the Col1, Col2 and Col3 in a concatenated fashion. Then you can set the condition for visibility on these two sets of textboxes. i.e. If Col2 and Col3 are NULL, hide the top 3 text boxes and make the fourth visible. On the other hand if Col2 or Col3 are not NULL, show the top 3 and hide the fourth one.

Comment: This is for getting the string into the 4th textbox:

`=Fields!Col1.Value+ Fields!Col2.Value + Fields!Col3.Value`

This is for setting condition for "Hidden" for the 4th textbox:

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Col2.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!Col3.Value), FALSE, TRUE)` 

This is for setting "Hidden" condition for the other 3 textboxes:

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Col2.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!Col3.Value), TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but after I'm using this, It not hiding `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. Added 4th column and only if 2 and 3 are nulls It keeps value from col1, in other way hidding cell of col4 (but no action for 1,2 ,3 columns).

Comment: That's not possible. The two statements do the exact opposite. If one hides, the other should show and vice versa.  Are you sure you are using the correct expressions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this by using an expression for each of the cells in a row like this:

Column 1:

```
=iif(isNothing(col2) AND isNothing(col3), "", col1)
```

Column 2:

```
=iif(isNothing(col2) AND isNothing(col3), col1, col2)
```

Column 3:

```
=iif(isNothing(col2) AND isNothing(col3), "", col3)
```

This sort of bypasses the need to merge, which should be faster and easier to implement.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question a bit. But I think that a good approach here would be to create two rows within the same group and set one of the rows to be visible when col2 and col3 are null; this row will have the 3 cells merged with a placeholder for the value of col1. Then create another row that is visible only when col2 or col3 is not null, and have this row contain 3 separate cells, each with it's own col placeholder. I've tested this and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try IsNothing instead of = NULL ?

EX: =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value),Fields!MyFields.Value,Fields!MyFields.Value)

If needed use IIF condition again...

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but how to use It for merge cells?
`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Col1.Value),Fields!Col2.Value,Fields!Col3.Value)` What this exactly do? Checking if any of them are empty?

Comment: For now this only delete value from first col if col2 and col3 are empty, so all 3 empty. It not keeping value and not merging cells.